# Crashes when setting UITableViewCell delegate in Xcode beta 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, swift

I got an error: **"EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0xffffffffffffffff8)"** when I was trying to set the delegate of my UITableViewCell.

Here is my UITableViewCell:

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func onButtonClicked(theCell : MyCell)
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

    var delegate : MyCellDelegate?
```

The UIViewController which includes a tableview who use the tableview cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as MyCell
    cell.lblTitle.text = ...
    cell.lblDescription.text = ...
    cell.delegate = self // ***Crashes*** here
```

It seems the same code works on Beta 3. Can anybody help? (I don't know how to debug this kind of error for Swift. Because all the commands such as **po** doesn't work at all.)

Comment: Stupid question... but `self` here implements the `MyCellDelegate` protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding @objc solved the problem.

```
@objc protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func onButtonClicked(theCell : MyCell)
}
```